# Unable to install app. Could not inspect the application package

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, package, failed-installation

My app builds successfully but when it starts installing on the iPhone device it fails with the following message:

```
Details
Unable to install "AppName"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-08-10 15:43:15 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000121ed79d1 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000121f13ce7 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c25f7d6 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000121f13a1d -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1422
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000121c62668 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 3414
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c3913d4 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c3924bc __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 372
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80eac90cc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80eaca317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80ead0317 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80ead0dfd _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80eadaeee _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 753
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80ec7dfd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80ec7cf57 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone9,3";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.5 (19F77)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 4001;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402653103";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.6.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.5";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.5";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--
System Information
macOS Version 12.4 (Build 21F79)
Xcode 13.4.1 (20504) (Build 13F100)
Timestamp: 2022-08-10T16:43:15+01:00
```

I don't know why this is happening. I'm guessing because of some external 3rd party frameworks which I have embedded.

I am using 3rd party frameworks for example:

- FirebaseCore.framework
- FirebaseInstallations.framework
- GoogleUtilities.framework
- GoogleAppMeasurement.framework
- etc.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have same errors when switch using google and firebase xcframeworks to pods.  The installing logs aren't clarified. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to solve it by setting some of the 3rd party frameworks from **Embed & Sign** to **Do not embed** in target -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.

Now the app runs on the iPhone.